# Файл sitemap.xml в ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, sitemap

Где в проекте ASP.NET Core (Razor Pages) нужно разместить файл sitemap.xml

Comment: А разве нельзя этот файл сгенерировать программными способами? https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/24.5.php — вот здесь рассказано, как настроить sitemap и заставить его работать

Comment: Ваша ссылка указывает на генерацию sitemap.xml в ASP.NET MVC.  А я хотел понять куда данный файл нужно разместить в Razor Pages. Структура папок этих проектов отличается. И мне не нужно генерировать файл, он у меня уже готов.

Comment: Спасибо за интересный вопрос, сейчас как раз начал изучение Razor Pages.  Если исходить из логики, по которой строится структура файлов и папок в ASP.NET Core вообще, и Razor Pages в частности, то все статические файлы нужно хранить в папке wwwroot, где к ним можно обращаться из любой страницы, по ссылке. По аналалогии так же, как и к картинкам, файлам JS и так далее.. Попробуйте это сделать, но я не уверен что это именно так.

Comment: Пробовал разместить файл .xml в папке wwwroot и в корне проекта (папка Pages). После запуска проекта браузер файл не видит - отображает пустую страницу. Хотя например файл .json из папки wwwroot отображается нормально.

Comment: Проблема однако, слежу за вашим вопросом, мне тоже интересно как это решить.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Отсюда работает sitemap. Методом тыка нашёл.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]